# Copy constructor question Lippman

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I was trying to solve a copy ctro qs given in lipman n not sure If i got it right. Since the class has pointers to itself it confused me a bit. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class BinStrTreeNode{

      public:
         BinStrTreeNode(const string& val):_val(val){ 
              _leftchild = new BinStrTreeNode("nup");
              _rightchild = new BinStrTreeNode("rup");
              cout << "ctor" << endl;
         };
         BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode&);
     private:
         string _val;
         BinStrTreeNode *_leftchild;
         BinStrTreeNode *_rightchild;
};

BinStrTreeNode::BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode& rhs):_val(rhs._val){
    cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
    _leftchild = new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._leftchild));
    _rightchild = new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._rightchild));
}
```

And it gives segementation fault. I know i need to define a dtor too but first I need to get this right. How should i define a copy ctor, assignment operator for a class like this?

Thanks

Comment: When it gives segmentation fault? What operations provoke it? Your code doesn't contain any clue.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with tabs, there's something wrong with the OP. Also, notice there's a space (not a tab) before public but not private. If your program converts tabs to spaces sure, wonderful, but no big deal IMHO. His source is using too many spaces for a tab, if he is infact using tabs.. I don't even think he is, they are not aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got it basically correct.
You just forgot to check for NULL pointers.

```
BinStrTreeNode::BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode& rhs)
    :_val(rhs._val)
    ,_leftchild(NULL)
    ,_rightchild(NULL)
{
    cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
    if (rhs._leftchild  != NULL) {_leftchild  = new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._leftchild));}
    if (rhs._rightchild != NULL) {_rightchild = new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._rightchild));}
}
```

Note trees will not point to a node higher (or self) in the tree (as that would no longer be a tree it would be a graph). If your code is a graph then you need to re-write this so that you do a graph copy which is a lot more complex as you need to track which nodes have been copied in a map.

Though personally I would take it a step further and do everything in the initializer list:
Though I would just say that this is a personal preference.

```
BinStrTreeNode::BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode& rhs)
    :_val(rhs._val)
    ,_leftchild ((rhs._leftchild  == NULL)?NULL:new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._leftchild)))
    ,_rightchild((rhs._rightchild == NULL)?NULL:new BinStrTreeNode(*(rhs._rightchild)))
{
    cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
}
```

#### Cycle trees (AKA Graphs)

Lets start from scratch here:
In this situation we need to track each node we create. Then when a pointer points back a node that has already been copied we use the copied node rather than creating a new one (otherwise we end up in a recursive nightmare following the loop round and around and around).

```
typedef std::map<BinStrTreeNode*,BinStrTreeNode*>   CopyMap;
BinStrTreeNode::BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode& rhs)
    :_val(rhs._val)
{
    CopyMap    copyMap;
    copyMap[&rhs] = this;

    left  = copyGraph(left,copyMap);
    right = copyGraph(right,copyMap) 
}

private:
BinStrTreeNode* BinStrTreeNode::copyGraph(BinStrTreeNode* node,CopyMap& copyMap)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {    return NULL;
    }

    if (copyMap[node] != NULL)
    {    return copyMap[ndoe];
    }

    return new BinStrTreeNode(*node, copyMap);
}
BinStrTreeNode::BinStrTreeNode(const BinStrTreeNode& rhs, CopyMap& copyMap)
    :_val(rhs._val)
{
    copyMap[&rhs] = this;
    left  = copyGraph(left,copyMap);
    right = copyGraph(right,copyMap) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is recursive.  You might have exhausted memory or had new throw an out of memory exception or, most likely, dereferenced a null pointer in one of the copy constructor invocations.

Comment: The other constructor has the same problem: recursive methods need base cases, otherwise they never stop running.

Comment: That's what's confusing me, so how do I define a copy ctor for a class that has pointers to itself?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that both the constructors infinitely recurse:

- Your constructor will recurse until you get a stack overflow, or until `new` throws a `std::bad_alloc`.
- Your copy constructor will recurse until you get a stack overflow, or until it encounters an invalid leftchild or right child, when it will segfault.

Your underlying problem is that your recursive functions don't have a terminating condition. All functions, including constructors, need a code path that doesn't recurse.

Comment: Yeah, I do get it now. I think putting a breaking condition of _leftchild, _rightchild being null might solve my problem here.

Comment: Yep. You'll also have to alter the other constructor to set leftchild and rightchild to null under some conditions.